# Serial Execution of Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I would like to execute a function with a parameter looping from an array of values. Every execution must waits the previous to be completed.
The example code below should print:

```
Done: 1
Done: 2
Done: 3
Done: 4
Done: 5
```

Thanks!

p.

```js
'use strict';

function f1(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Done: ' + value);
            resolve(true)
        }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
    });
}

const vs = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

vs.reduce((start, next) => {
    return f1(next)
})
```

Comment: I made this using angularjs promises however exactly the same can be done with native. https://gist.github.com/ste2425/608b74d20504d526d2c08dd8fa76f675

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just ES6, try this:

```
'use strict';

function f1(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Done: ' + value);
            resolve(true)
        }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
    });
}

const vs = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

let promiseChain = vs.reduce((start, next) => {
    return start.then(() => f1(next));
}, Promise.resolve());

promiseChain.then(() => console.log('Done!'));
```

If you're interested in getting the values out of the resolutions, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901476/making-a-for-loop-wait-without-a-library-in-js/36901732#36901732) as well.

Comment: It's what I'd try to do! Thanks

Comment: Or just `vs.reduce((p, v) => p.then(() => f1(v)), Promise.resolve())`.

Comment: Right, same thing. I just opted for multiple lines and re-using the variable names from the question to (hopefully) improve readability.